# com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException Exception opening socket

Tags: java, mongodb, amazon-ec2

**Problem statement:**
I have two Amazon EC2 instances running on same VPC. One ec2 is running web application (a spring mvc java website), while second instance is running mongodb.

I can do ssh from my local machine to both instances as well as to two instances from each other. Also telnet works perfectly fine from each other using private ip.

I also can connect to ec2 mongodb instance from my personal (local) workspace, as necessary rules are created to accept connections from local and web application's ec2 instance.

However, my web application instance cannot connect to this mongodb instance and throwing following exception whenever trying to load index page.

Exception:

```
com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[xxx.xx.xx.xxx:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server xxx.xx.xx.xxx:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:113)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Permission denied (connect failed)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:57)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58)
    ... 3 more

com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
INFO: No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary} from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, serverDescriptions=[ServerDescription{address=xxx.xx.xx.xxx:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Permission denied (connect failed)}}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
```

**Other details:**
- Two security group have been created. 1 for Web application 2 Mongodb
- EC2 Web application is running on RHEL + Java 1.8 + Tomcat
- EC2 Mongo instance is running on RHEL (followed instructions from https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-red-hat/)
- Java Driver is used to connect to MongoDB is { driver: { name: "mongo-java-driver", version: "3.4.1" }
- bind_ip is set to 0.0.0.0 and no administrative security at this moment.

**Assumption:**
I am certain that mongodb ec2 instance is accepting connection as i can connect from local workspace.

Any clue or direction in this regards will be really helpful. Thanks.

bind_ip set to 0.0.0.0

Security groups are accepting connections from pretty much everywhere and inbound and outbound 0.0.0.0/0

iptables rules set for INPUT and OUTPUT on both instances.

Comment: did you restart mongodb after setting bindip to 0.0.0.0?

Comment: yes. it was restarted as a result i can connect from my local pc